# passing input value using jquery on mysql query

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, post

I have following html form:

```
 <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="userid" id="user" value="<?php echo $user ?>"/>
    <textarea name="comment" class="subcomment_form" id="ctextarea<?php echo $suggestid ?>"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Post" id="<?php echo $suggestid ?>" class="form_btn" style="margin-top: 5px"/>
 </form>
```

following JS code:

```
$('.form_btn').live("click",function() 
{

var ID = $(this).attr("id");

var user= $("input[name=userid]").val();
var comment= $("#ctextarea"+ID).val();
var dataString = 'comment='+ comment + '&suggestid=' + ID + 'user' + user;

if(comment=='')
{
alert("Please Enter Comment Text");
}
else
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "action/subcomment.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$("#commentload"+ID).append("html");
$("#ctextarea"+ID).val('');
$("#ctextarea"+ID).focus();
 }
 });
}
return false;
});
```

and following php code for subcomment.php file:

```
if($_POST['comment'])
{
$comment=$_POST['comment'];
$suggestid=$_POST['suggestid'];
$user=$_POST['user'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_suggestions_comments (uvd_id, user_id, usc_comment) VALUES ('".$_POST['suggestid']."', '".$_POST['user']."','".$_POST['comment']."')";
mysql_query( $sql);
}
```

the problem I have is that value from `<input type="hidden" name="userid" id="user" value="<?php echo $user ?>"/>` is not passed on php file and textarea content is passed. What I need to change inside that JS code to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your dataString is not being built to what your PHP code is expecting.
Try this change.

```
var dataString = 'comment='+ comment + '&suggestid=' + ID + 'user' + user;
```

becomes

```
var dataString = 'comment='+ comment + '&suggestid=' + ID + '&user=' + user;
```

You are looking for three values from your $_POST and only passing 2

```
$comment=$_POST['comment'];
$suggestid=$_POST['suggestid'];
$user=$_POST['user'];
```

Comment: Yeah I was assuming that he just passed the form as is I dont know why he is changing it into a data string...

Comment: thanks a lot to both of you, by adding & in front of user worked :)

Comment: It looks like he's changing it to a data string because the suggestId is built from data that wouldn't be submitted normally.
But I would say it's best to keep the names in the data string the same as if the form were submitted naturally.  Just makes things clearer.